# if $V$ is closed, $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis

> If $h : S\to T$  is a map between two sets, and $X\subseteq T$, we define $$h^{-1}(X)= \{s\in S:h(s)\in X\}.$$ Prove that if $\mathbf f=(f,g):\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ is continuous (defined by a pair of continuous functions $$f(x,y),g(x,y)):(f,g)(x,y)=(f(x,y),g(x,y)),$$
>   then (a) if $V$ is closed, $f^{-1}(V)$ is closed;$\qquad$(b) if $U$ is open, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.

I don't see it's true. For example, in $\mathbb R^1$, $[1,\infty)$ is closed, but $(0,1]$ is not closed.($f=1/x$)

Comment: Be careful. What is the domain of $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: ... and $f$ is not a map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ (therefore, it is not a continuous map either).

Comment: Thanks! But how to prove?

Comment: Show it by contradiction. Take an open set $U$, and consider what happens when $f^{-1}(U)$ is not open (i.e. there is at least one point that does not have any neighborhood contained entirely in $f^{-1}(U)$). Note that (a) follows from (b).

Comment: @MichaelLee Do you mean the image of any neighborhood of that point can not lie entirely inside $U$, so $U$ is not open?

Comment: Take the point $x\in f^{-1}(U)$ that has no neighborhood contaned entirely in $f^{-1}(U)$, and use this to take a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset \mathbb{R}^2\setminus f^{-1}(U)$ such that $x_n\to x$. We cannot have $f(x_n)\to f(x)$, as $f(x_n)$ never enters $U$, which is a neighborhood of $f(x)$. This would imply that $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Preimages of open sets being open is the *definition* of continuity. What is there to be shown here?